# mongoDB OPS Manager trial?

Tags: mongodb

I am using MongoDB 3.4 in my local machine with Community edition. I want to install mongoDb OPS manager in my local machine, before I need some clarification, MongoDB OPS Manager providing any trail periods or not?

How to access mongoDB OPS Manager freely for atleast 30 days?

please any one help me !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ops manager is also free for use. It can be downloaded from here: https://www.mongodb.com/download-center?jmp=docs&_ga=1.71891025.331379185.1490105828#ops-manager

The only thing MongoDB charge is for enterprise advanced version and customer support products only rest of all the services and products are free of cost.

Answer (score 1):

@karthickkumar-nagaraj maybe the license of ops-manager has changed in the meantime but currently (May 2020) mongodb.com states the following:

> Ops Manager is available as part of the MongoDB Enterprise Advanced
>   subscription ...

Source: https://www.mongodb.com/download-center/ops-manager

MongoDB Enterprise Advanced subscription **is not free**.

However, you may use OpsManager free of charge for **evaluation and development**.